# bayespy - how to compute posterior probability if observations are output of fuzzy rules

Tags: python-3.x, bayesian-networks, inference, fuzzy

following the example from:
http://bayespy.org/examples/hmm.html

```
a0 = [0.6, 0.4] # p(rainy)=0.6, p(sunny)=0.4
A = [[0.7, 0.3], # p(rainy->rainy)=0.7, p(rainy->sunny)=0.3
     [0.4, 0.6]] # p(sunny->rainy)=0.4, p(sunny->sunny)=0.6

N = 100 # will be observing 100 samples

# discrete first-order Markov chain is constructed as
from bayespy.nodes import CategoricalMarkovChain
Z = CategoricalMarkovChain(a0, A, states=N)

# observations
# probability of each activity depends on the current weather
P = [[0.1, 0.4, 0.5], # walk, shop, clean for rainy weather
     [0.6, 0.3, 0.1]]

# observed process using P and chain Z
from bayespy.nodes import Categorical, Mixture
Y = Mixture(Z, Categorical, P)

# DATA

# generate artificial data from the model itself.
# Realisation of weather process
weather = Z.random()

# using weather process, draw realisations of activities
activity = Mixture(weather, Categorical, P).random()

# INFERENCE
#using weather and activities data, 
#we set our variable Y to be observed:
Y.observe(activity)

# variational Bayesian inference engine with all random variables
from bayespy.inference import VB
Q = VB(Y, Z)

# is only one unobserved random variable, we recover the exact posterior 
distribution
Q.update()
```

how should I use Bayespy if the states of activity (the observed variable) are not a Categorical set but belonging to a distribution that is a fuzzy membership activation for each activity? E.g. instead of the states of activity being mutually independent like walk or clean or shop, one could walk and shop at the same time to a certain degree in a fuzzy framework e.g. 80% walk and 20% clean, hence:

- what model (Gaussian, Categorical, Mixture, ..) should I define for my fuzzy observed activities? i.e. change Categorical with?

`activity = Mixture(weather, Categorical, P).random()`